# Export png file from plot2d in wxMaxima

Tags: plot, export, png, maxima

Is there a way to export graphics of functions that results from (wx)plot2d in (wx)Maxima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `png_file` as an argument to plot:

```
plot2d(sin(x),[x,0,2], [png_file, "test_sin.png"]);
```

`pdf_file`, `ps_file` and `svg_file` are also supported.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no eps_file ... But thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can save a plot as a pdf file. If you using wxmaxima use the plot function in the menu bar. Choose Gnuplot as plot format. Once the plot is drawn click on the plot and choose to save as from the edit menu. Select pdf.

Comment: You mean the edit menu on the Gnuplot pop-up window, right? I often use that method, in my experience the Gnuplot pdf output looks nice. The user can also choose "copy to clipboard" in the Gnuplot window, that's useful to paste into an email or other document.

Comment: Yes. The output does look nice.  And it can be converted from psd to other image formats.

Comment: This works too, but I rather use commands than menus. Thanks anyway!